# Inkscape pdf to svg export - retain hyperlinks

Tags: inkscape

When doing an SVG export from inkscape I would like to retain hyperlinks that exist inside the PDF (to both pages within the pdf and external web pages). Any ideas?

```
inkscape --without-gui --file=D:\data\samples\example.pdf --export-plain-svg=D:\data\samples\example.svg
```

Comment: For 1.0, this has been implemented for the other direction, as far as I know. Can you try it out with the latest beta version and make a feature request if it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks @Moini. I tried with the beta version and it didn't work. I will file a feature request.

Comment: Note: if the PDF file happens to be generated with TeX, another option is to compile to DVI first with `[hypertex]` option, then use dvisvgm. Refer to https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm/issues/75